# UIBarButtonItem not responding to touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I don't know what wrong but my UIBarButtonItems in a UIToolBar aren't responding. I have a splitviewcontroller and the bar button item that is implemented with the template isn't responding either. It literally doesn't even change it's tint when click. I created a new UIViewController , presented it as a modal view controller. The vc has a toolbar and a barbuttonitem, and the bar button item is hooked up to an IBAction. That's not responding either. Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you set the .userInteractionEnabled (BOOL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well by default in the viewcontroller.xib should have touch enabled, but just in case you should check the properties inside the viewcontroller of the UIBar and see if buttonpress is enabled or whatever option for interaction is in the xib

Comment: The user interaction is enabled for both the UITabBar and the UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: Well I don't know what else could be wrong... double check and make sure you did everything right http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/03_AddingViewController.html